# Como reescrever esse codigo em vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

[image: funcao de vue js]

queria reescrever esse codigo em vue.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, benvindo ao StackOverflow

Quando à sua pergunta, sendo que o VueJs é muito flexivel, há várias maneiras de fazer o que pergunta, mas uma delas pode ser:

```html
<div :class="wrapClass">
    <button @click.prevent="toggleClass">Toggle class</button>
</div>
```

e no script, algo como

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      wrapClass: 'class1' // class inicial
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleClass() {
      this.wrapClass = this.wrapClass === 'class1' 
        ? ''       // remove a class
        : 'class1' // adiciona a class
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

- `:class="wrapClass` ao comecar um atributo com `:` estamos a dizer ao Vue que a palavra dentro de aspas, é uma variavel e näo uma string
- `@click.prevent="toggleClass"` sendo que `@` é o mesmo que `v-on:` estamos a dizer ao Vue que no evento `click` queremos que ele execute um metodo, e adicionamos `.prevent` para prevenir que o browser siga o "link" do botao
- o metodo é simples, e apenas usamos uma variavel `wrapClass` que contem a classe original, e quando executamos o metodo `toggleClass` mudamos de um para o outro valor

fica aqui um exemplo no CodePen: https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/poEGqyQ

Comment: Você não precisa utilizar o `.prevent` se usar o `<button>` adequadamente.
Por padrão o `<button>` toma como default o `type="submit"`, por isso o comportamento de submissão de formulário que você tenta previnir... Simplemente use `<button type="button" @click="toggleClass">...</button>` que assim não haverá esse comportamento de submissão de form.

Comment: eu entendo, mas ele pediu como reescrever o codigo, e se faz uso de tal funcao, eu mencionei tambem 